# Android Could not create parent directory for lock file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm trying to synch the project but at the time of synch getting below error

**Could not create parent directory for lock file /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.0-bin/ssads/gradle-8.0-bin.zip.lck**

Tried with gradle-7.2 still same error.

I have tried with updating gradle version but still the build is getting failed with below error

Could not create parent directory for lock file /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.0-bin/ssads/gradle-8.0-bin.zip.lck

want to resolve the issue.

quick help really healps

Answer (score 1):

Delete the "Gradle user home" path in settings... reopen Android Studio and you see the Gradle user home path changed to path of your profile.
[Gradle user home path settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc6Ga.jpg)